# Let $k$ be a positive integer and also let...

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

[image]
I do not know how to approach the above problem.Can someone help me in this regard?Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terms in the sum can only be $\frac 12, \frac 23, \frac 34, \ldots$.  Four of them are clearly too many,as the sum will be at least $2$, so A and D are out already.  The right side is at least $1$, so we can't have $1$ term, so B is out.  The answer must be C.

As a test question, this is sufficient, but it would be nice to show we can do $2$ and $3$.  $2$ is easy-take $n_1=n_2=n$ for any $n$.  For 3, take $n_1=n_2=n_3=2,n=4$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=1}^k\left(1-\frac{1}{n_i}\right)=1-\frac{1}{n_1}+1\frac{1}{n_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n_k}=k-\left(\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n_k}\right)$$

Since for any $\,1<n\in\Bbb N\,\,,\,\frac{1}{n}<1\,$ , we get:

$$k-\left(\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n_k}\right)\geq k-\frac{k}{\min\{n_1,...,n_k\}}\;\;,\text{ so...}$$

Comment: and so, $\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}+...+\frac{1}{n_k}\leq \frac{k}{min(n_1,n_2,...,n_k)}$. Now if without loss of generality,i take $n_1=1,n_2=2,$ then we get $k \geq (3/2)$. Now from here ,i can not progress.

Comment: @user53386:  you said $n_1 \gt 1$, so the minimum is at least $2$.  You probably should also not assume that all the $n_i$ are distinct-that was not specified.

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks a lot sir.I have got it.

Comment: @RossMillikan , $\,n>1\,$ is a basic info *you gave* and used explicitly above...